# Ajax form gets submitted multiple times

Tags: ajax, forms, yii2

I have an action in my controller which submits a new model.
The form is in a modal popup and i need a full ajax validation.
Everything works except the form is submitted multiple times continuosly.
It works if i remove the yiiActiveForm('validate') command, but i need it to validate before the submission.

```
$('#myformid').off('submit').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();


    var form = $(this);
    var formData = form.serializeArray();
    form.data('yiiActiveForm').submitting = true;
    form.yiiActiveForm('validate');

    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        type: form.attr("method"),
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {

            if(data !== false){
                $('#modal-add-associate').modal('hide');
            }
        },
        error: function () {

        }
    });
    return false;

});
```

The form starts with

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableAjaxValidation' => true,'validationUrl'=> $validationUrl]);
```

So usually is validated by ajax with a custom url (and it works except on submit).
How can i launch the validation when the form is getting submit?

Comment: You should use `beforeSubmit` event rather than `submit` event and just use `$('#myformid').on('beforeSubmit', function(e){}`, try it and tell me if it works also remove `e.stopImmediatePropagation();`

Comment: also what type of button you have for the submit is it of type `submit` or `button` i suspect you are using a button rather than `submit` type. and you dont need to use`form.data('yiiActiveForm').submitting = true;` or `form.yiiActiveForm('validate');` as it it automatically triggered using the submit button , if you have a `submit` button already then remove these lines too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `beforeSubmit` event rather than `submit` above all, as you are using the activeform and Yii2 `ActiveForm` provides you with the following form events

Available events are:

- [`beforeValidate`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js#L39).
- [`afterValidate`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js#L50).
- [`beforeValidateAttribute`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js#L64).
- [`afterValidateAttribute`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js#L74).
- [`beforeSubmit`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js#L83).
- [`ajaxBeforeSend`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js#L93).
- [`ajaxComplete`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.activeForm.js#L103).

Read More about [ActiveForms](https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/forms-activeform-js.md)

Looking at your javascript and the problem you don't need these lines

```
form.data('yiiActiveForm').submitting = true;
form.yiiActiveForm('validate');
```

because if you are using a `submit` type button for submitting the form the validation is automatically triggered as the option `validateOnSubmit` is by default `true` for the `ActiveForm` so you should remove them.

Make sure the Active Form has a `submit` type button the form should look like below

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableAjaxValidation' => true,'validationUrl'=> $validationUrl]);

//Your fields
//.....
//.....
echo Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn']); 
ActiveForm::end();
```

And you need to revise your javascript, you dont need to use `.off().on()` as the `beforeSubmit` will be called only once the form is validated and passes the validation, and you are using `type` option in `ajax` call, which is an alias for `method`. You should use `type` if you're using versions of jQuery prior to `1.9.0`. which isnt your case i think. ifyou are using the latest Yii version `2.0.16` then it includes Jquery `3.3.1` by default via `yii\web\JqueryAsset` so you can change it to `method`.

```
$('#myformid').on('beforeSubmit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);
    var formData = form.serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        method: form.attr("method"),
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data !== false) {
                $('#modal-add-associate').modal('hide');
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the beforeSubmit previously, but it didn't solve my problem. But will try it along the other changes you suggested.
One question though, about the submit button. Will the code work if the user just submits with the return button?

Comment: @dgtal, couldnot get what you mean by **Will the code work if the user just submits with the return button?** what do you mean by **return button**, are you saying that by clicking the submit button the above code will work correctly? yes it will work correctly.

Comment: Sorry i meant the return key, from the keyboard

Comment: the return key works by default with the button type `submit` @dgtal , it willl trigger the validation and submit the form too